# `alert` not showing in ManifestV3 background service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that alerts you in the tab that you are currently moving or highlighting. I have tried reading the chrome migrating to V.3 documentation and have come up with the following code, however, the alerts never appear. Does anybody know what I need to change or add?

```
// manifest.json

{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Alert",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "alerts you when doing tab functions",
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
}
```

```
//background.js

chrome.tabs.onMoved.addListener(function () {
    alert("You moved this tab");
});

chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(function () {
    alert("You highlighted this tab");
});
```

Working directory:

```
.
├── background.js
├── manifest.json
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`alert()` method cannot be used outside of the browser environment, you can use `console.warn()` or `console.error()` instead.  But is not a good solution if you want to show an error message to the extension user, as they would never open the console.

If you would like a more user friendly approach use the following:

```
chrome.notifications.create({
type: 'basic',
iconUrl: '/images/image_if_any.png',
title: `Notification title`,
message: "Your message",
priority: 1
});
```

Also add "notifications" to "permissions" in your manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [..., "notifications"]
```

Comment: Note: the "iconUrl" is actually required.

Answer (score 2):

`alert` is not defined in a service worker per specification so we'll have to use `console.log`

Also, I was looking in the wrong place for the alert messages. I needed to look at the service worker link in my unpacked extension page. [image]